# Proper Max Database Size and Max Buffer Size for Windows Mobile device with 128MB of RAM?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, windows-mobile-6.5

I have windows mobile device that has 128MB of RAM.

What should be the proper Max Database Size and Max Buffer Size for connection string that I use for SqlCe? ( I use Windows Mobile 6.5 and SqlCe 3.5)

Currently I have it set to 512 (for Max Database Size) and 4096 (for Max Buffer Size). I am running into some SqlCeException Not enough storage errors after opening connection 100 times or so.

Comment: Are you closing and disposing your connection each time? Or just opening it and leaving it hanging?

Comment: I am using `using` statement for connections, plus I close it in the end.

Comment: @Aaron: Opening a connection and "leaving it hanging" is the correct approach with SQL Server Compac - Armen: Setting max database size to lower (like 128 MB) will decrease memory usage - but I saw in another q that you are using DataSet - NOT recommended

Comment: @ErikEJ Was that comment directed at me? Why?

Comment: Yes, keyboard trouble, look at my updated comment